# Q: The integration of ATOM IDE with GitHub is still workin?

Tags: python, github, ide, integration, atom-editor

I have downloaded ATOM IDE to start coding in Python, but when I tried to login in my Github account in ATOM, for some reason when I enter a Token that I generate in Developer Options in my Github account (visiting github.atom.io/login is not working for me), the login does not do anything

[Github Login not workin in ATOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HShuS.png)

Is there a way to connect them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason now I am able to access github.atom.io/login and get the access token. So far so good, so I am closing this question.